# python: recursive function counter. persistence issue

Tags: python, recursion

Maybe some of you already tried to resolve "persistent bugger" task on codewars.
So here is my turn:)

```
def persistence(num):
  multi = 1
  while num:
    multi *= num % 10
    num /= 10
  global count
  count += 1
  if(multi >= 10):
    persistence(multi)
  else:
    return 0
  return count
count = 0
print(persistence(39))
#print(persistence(25))
```

It gives me correct iteration results and successful result of 1 try. `(persistence(39) => 3  # Because 3*9 = 27, 2*7 = 14, 1*4=4)` But because of using global variable I can't run it's more than 1 time. How to deal with this? How can I create counter and at this time use this function recursively?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're function is doing, but I'm guessing you are going to want to `return persistence(multi)` instead of just calling it. Also if you need to maintain a count, you can pass it as a second argument rather than calling a global. `def persistence(num, count):`

Comment: Since I'm not familiar with that "task," could you tell us what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: here is a question: Write a function, persistence, that takes in a positive parameter num and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single digit.
`persistence(39) => 3`, `persistence(25) => 2`. So I should return `count`. In my case I use global var. That's why counter always increases and I get in second run 5 (3+2) instead of just 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recursion, if you need to manage state, you manage it within the arguments of the function:

```
def persistence(num):
  #here is your code, slightly modified.
  def _persist(num,count=0):
    multi = 1
    while num:
      multi *= num % 10
      num /= 10
    if(multi >= 10):
      return _persist(multi,count+1)
    else:
      return count
  return _persist(num)
```

where you're effectively presenting one interface for your function but you're really calling it recursively via `_perist`.

Comment: Does this outer function return something?

Comment: @ascentman yes, you'd nest the same code as he had written in his question. So the `_persist` would return `count`.

Comment: I can't get but as a result I get: "1" and "1". I also removed global definition of `count`. After calling inner function a default value of count (zero) is used every time.

Comment: @wheties, Oo...thanks! Now I understood my fault with increasing `count`

Answer (score 4):

Your attempt is good but the approach is quite naive, and has its little flaw. Using `global` to keep count across the recursive calls of a function has the problem of using the same count variable for subsequent new *unrelated* calls; and that's why you currently have that problem.

You can instead count the number of times your function does a recursion by incrementing the returned value by 1 and returning a `0` in the last call. The final count is then the accumulated count after all recursive calls.

Here's one way to do it with `operator.mul` and `functools.reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

def persistence(num):
    if len(str(num)) == 1:
        return 0
    val = reduce(operator.mul, map(int, str(num)))
    return 1 + persistence(val)

print(persistence(39))
# 3
print(persistence(25))
# 2
```

Comment: @Copperfield Thanks. That's the curse of *retrofitting*

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with a while loop!

```
def persistence(n):
    loop_count = 0
    while len(str(n)) != 1:
        i = 1
        for number in str(n):
            i = int(number) * i
        n = i
        loop_count += 1
    return loop_count
```